# Mysql - Operation like IN which matches all values

Tags: mysql

I have a table Orders which contains CustID and BookNo of customers who have ordered Books.
I have another table Books which contains all the BookNo.

I want to display all CustIDs who have ordered all the BookNo.

Something like the 'IN' function which matches all values in the set as 'AND' instead of 'OR' would be handy.

Any quick clues, if not an answer?

Answer (score 0):

To get only customers that ordered all books you can group by each customers and then count the number of books a customer ordered and compare it with the total number of books

```
select c.custid 
from customers c
inner join books b on b.bookno = c.bookno
group by c.custid
having count(distinct b.bookno) = (select count(distinct bookno) from books)
```

Answer (score 0):

select custId from Orders group by CustID having count(*) = (select count(distinct bookNo) from Books);

Answer (score 0):

Not aware of a way to do that using `IN` or similar, but a simple `GROUP BY`/`HAVING` should do that nicely. The `DISTINCT` is added to make sure two orders of the same book still counts as just one book.

```
SELECT CustID
FROM Orders
GROUP BY CustID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT BookNo) = (SELECT COUNT(BookNo) FROM Books);
```

[An SQLfiddle for testing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55ce7/1).